# Sorting NSMutableArray By Object's Property

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdate

So this is a rather basic question regarding the best way to sort an `NSMutableArray` of custom objects.

I have a an `NSMutableArray` of custom objects, each object with an `NSString` and `NSDate` that go together. I need to sort the array by the newest object (so latest `NSDate`), and I'm pretty sure I could simply use `NSDate compare: NSDate` if this was an array of just `NSDate`, but since I need all objects to be sorted and not just the date, I'm not sure if I can use that method.

In terms of pseudo-code, I need to: Look at individual object, determine if the current object's `NSDate` is the next biggest in the array, and if it is, move the object, not just the date.

Again, this is something I was even hesitant to ask since it's so basic but I don't want to go writing some grossly inefficient method if there is a pre-existing class method that will essentially do what I want, search an array of object's sub properties and sort the objects according to the subproperties.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[`NSSortDescriptors`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s make this really simple. With `NSMutableArray` you can sort the existing array using `sortUsingDescriptors:` and with immutable arrays you create a new array using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`

```
//This will sort by stringProperty ascending, then dateProperty ascending
[mutable_array sortUsingDescriptors:
 @[
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"stringProperty" ascending:YES],
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateProperty" ascending:YES]
  ]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be just what I'm looking for!

Comment: Looks like I should have done a little more research too, this question was exactly my problem as well for anyone in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083408/sort-nsarray-of-custom-objects-by-their-nsdate-properties

Answer (score 21):

This little snippet worked great for me:

```
[students sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];
```