# Inserting Objects in Order NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have this array1 which contains dictionaries like this:

```
array1:  (
    {
   ordering = 18;
},
    {
   ordering = 22;
}
)
```

and i have array2 which contains arrays of dictionaries like this:

```
array2: (
    (
            {
             ordering = 17;
  },
   {
             ordering = 29;
}
),
    (
            {
            ordering = 23;
      }
   )
)
```

Now i want to insert the first array from array2({ordering=17}) before the dictionary with {ordering=18} and the second array from array2({ordering=23}) after the dictionary {ordering=22} in array1.Something like this:

```
array1=( 
    (
            {
             ordering = 17;
      },
 {
         ordering = 29;
 }
),
   {
   ordering = 22;
 },
  (
            {
            ordering = 23;
        }
     )
)
```

Can this be done?Please let me know if anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Can this be done? **YES**, Please let me know if anyone knows how to do this? **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001597/sorting-nsmutablearray-by-objects-property**

Comment: Please check my edited question.i don't think sortDescriptor will give the exact result i want no?

Comment: This style must be called "devils indentation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to do it in two steps.  Use `insertObjectsFromArray:` to put the new ones at the end of the existing array and then `sortUsingComparator:` to order them.

Comment: Please check my edited question the exact result i want in array1.sorting will change that order too no?

Comment: When you write the comparator block it will use any logic you give it to decide the ordering.